# Email to multiple users from Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to send multple emails to some users from an excel table. My table contains several users and for each of them I have some row with some actions.

```
        action              user
        ===============     =====
row1    lore ipsum 1        user1
        lore ipsum 2        
        lore ipsum 4        
        lore ipsum 5        
row2    lore ipsum 3        user2
        lore ipsum 1        
row3    lore ipsum 2        user3
```

It's a pivot table and all I need to do is to send each user a mail of this type:

Hello ""user""
you have those actions in this month:

""lore ipsum1""
""lore ipsum2""
""lore ipsum3""

I know I could use Word to make that but I can't add the multiple actions for the users that have more than one row. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: [related](http://superuser.com/questions/621756/excel-divide-informations#comment773159_621756)

Comment: Take a look at [this site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm) to see what you might be able to come up with

Comment: Can you not get your pivot table to print one row for each user, with 'lore ipsum x' the value of each subsequent column in that row? (depends on how many different types of `lore ipsum`s there are, i guess).  Otherwise a macro that loops til it finds the next user will do it.

Comment: What's your email client? outlook? What version of excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use VBA in Excel to send mails** (If you have Outlook installed)

This example is assuming a simple Excel table in this format.
[image]

```
Sub SendMailsFromList()
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    With ActiveSheet
         For i = 2 To .Columns(1).Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
         
            Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
            objMail.To = CStr(.Cells(i, 1))
            objMail.Subject = .Cells(i, 2)
            objMail.Body = .Cells(i, 3)
            objMail.Send
            Set objMail = Nothing
        
        Next i
    End With

    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

1. Set up your data table like the screenshot is showing
2. Open Excels VBA editor with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
3. Copy & paste the code above somewhere
4. Go back to Excel and execute the macro with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

You can also fill CC, BCC or use different signatures if desired. If we can have a closer look at your Pivot table, the code could be modified to work with your Workbook.

#### Used ressources

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg508919.aspx